# Asp.net mvc2: How to add validation rules - A number field is not required but has range limitation?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

Asp.net mvc2:  How to add validation rules - A number field is not required but has range limitation?

Comment: This question is pretty thin; if you add more detail, showing perhaps what you have and what is not working, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: How can a number be optional but still have a restricted range?  I'm pretty sure null is not between 1 and 10.

Comment: Using the Required attribute will not allow 0 whereas a Range attribute from 0 to 255 will.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Range Attribute from DataAnnotations.

```
[Range(0, 255, ErrorMessage="The number must be between 0 and 255.")]
```